# Customize lombok super builder

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I have a parent abstract class "Parent" and child class "Child". I am using @SuperBuilder to generate builder APIs. Now, I want to perform some validations on the members of class "Parent" and "Child" as part of build. I couldn't find any solution to customize lombok super builder. As per [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) doc, it seems to be possible. Can someone please shed some light?

```
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int a;
}

@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Child extends Parent {
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;

    // I want something like
    public static class ChildBuilder {

       public Child build() {
           Child child = // Get child somehow;
           validate(child);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generated code for `@SuperBuilder` is complex and loaded with type parameters. Therefore, it is advisable to `delombok` your class and use the output as a reference.

You can do this with this command:

```
java -jar path/to/lombok.jar delombok -p path/to/src/main/java/Child.java
```

The output will show what code lombok generates. I assume the `Child` class is not abstract (I think you have a typo in your questions). You want to customize the `build()` method, so you are interested in the `ChildBuilderImpl`, because this class contains that method. You can copy the class header to your source file and add your custom `build()` method:

```
private static final class ChildBuilderImpl extends Child.ChildBuilder<Child, Child.ChildBuilderImpl> {
    @java.lang.Override
    public Child build() {
        // Do validation here, e.g.:
        if (((Child.ChildBuilder<?, ?>)this).b == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("b must not be 0");
        return new Child(this);
    }
}
```

Remark: I would prefer performing the validation in the constructor, because otherwise you could programmatically invoke the constructor without the values getting validated. However, customizing the `@SuperBuilder` constructor is not possible at the moment; it will be possible with the next lombok release. I'll update this question when it is released.

Update: You can customize the constructor since Lombok v1.18.16.