# @SuperBuilder in lombok don't override method build()?

Tags: java, lombok

I use **@SuperBuilder()** in 2 class, I want override method build() of class child builder but it appear error "**Abstract method 'build()' cannot be accessed directly**" in line super.build() in **ClassChild**

```
Version Lombok: 1.18.28
Version java: 17
```

**ClassParent.java**

```
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ClassParent {
    private String name;
}
```

**ClassChild.java**

```
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClassChild extends ClassParent {
    private int age;

    public static ClassChildBuilder builder() {
        return new BuilderCustom();
    }

    public static class BuilderCustom extends ClassChildBuilder {

        public ClassChild build() {
            ClassChild classChild = super.build();
            return classChild;
        }

        @Override
        protected ClassChildBuilder self() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
ClassChild classChild = ClassChild.builder().name("Tom").age(20).build();
```

How should I fix to override the build() method success?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize lombok super builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658719/customize-lombok-super-builder)